# Split DateTime to Date and Time in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, mvc-editor-templates

I have read through [Scott Hanselman's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx) on this topic. I found [another article](http://devblog.lundy.us/2010/09/28/date-time-picker-asp-net-mvc-jquery-part-1/) that seems to be a simpler approach. The second of which I decided to try.

However, the first portion in creating the EditorTemplates is not working for me. I copied DateTime.ascx and TimeSpan.ascx has the author had them written. Then I split the fields in my view.

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.LeaveRequest.DateOfLeave)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <div class="date-container">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LeaveRequest.DateOfLeave.Date)%>
        </div>
        <div class="time-container">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LeaveRequest.DateOfLeave.TimeOfDay)%>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LeaveRequest.DateOfLeave)%>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem I am having is that the behavior I am getting is not the same that that author explained as should happen. Here is a screenshot of my results.

[image: Screenshot showing full DateTime in first field and all zeros in the second]

I must be missing something, but I can't tell what. I have read this article several times and can't see what I am missing. I am guessing there needs to be something to tell the program to us the new EditorTemplates, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed the fact that both Scott's solution and the solution you link to don't do:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LeaveRequest.DateOfLeave.Date) %>
```

Instead they use:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.LeaveRequest.DateOfLeave.Date) %>
```

And then utilize a custom editor to limit the field to just the Date (instead of both the date and time).

Scroll down to the **Separate the Date / Time fields** header of the article you link to and read a little bit closer about custom editor templates.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a default value on the client side if you'd like.

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LeaveRequest.DateOfLeave.Date,
new { @Value= DateTime.Now })%>
```

This sets the initial Texbox value to the current `DateTime` but you can obviously set it to whatever you like.